# Angular itkn error caused by directives defined with function outside array

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 1.3.15, also have tried 1.2.28, along with angular bootstrap. Last night, after updating Chrome to v42.0.2311.90, I suddenly began seeing tons of angular itkn errors:

```
Error: [$injector:itkn] Incorrect injection token! Expected service name as string, got function ()
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/itkn?p0=function%20()
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:63)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4189)
    at angular.min.js?bust=undefined:6525
    at forEach (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:323)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:6523)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4204)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4056)
    at Object.invoke (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4204)
    at angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4021
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.min.js?bust=undefined:4162)
```

This wasn't happening before updating Chrome but I guess I can't say that's for sure related.

After poking through, I've found that any directives defined like this:

```
  .directive('modalTransclude', function () {
    return {
      // directive code
    };
  })
```

Will cause this `itkn` error. I console.logged the `key` in the `$inject` iterator in angular and it's returning the function of the directive itself rather than only strings like was clearly intended.

I've discovered that wrapping the function in an array, even without any strings defining the injections, it solves the issue:

```
  .directive('modalTransclude', [function () {
    return {
      // directive code
    };
  }])
```

However, this error is not happening on the angular bootstrap site, and I've tried this on both angular 1.3 and 1.2 versions.

I'll continue looking for any causes that are unique to my app, but does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: same thing happening for me on Chrome, although just for my bootstrap modals. Just tested on Firefox and they appear to be working there

Comment: I can confirm that this directive issue is only affecting my angular bootstrap stuff. Any custom directives I have on my own work fine, whether with or without brackets.

Comment: Do you have http://ng-inspector.org/ installed in your chrome? For me, if I switch off ng-inspector, everything returns back to normal mode. Not sure what is exact reason of this, have no time to dive into it. This behaviour appeared very recently for me as well.

Comment: I do! I don't know why I didn't think about this. That solved the problem! If you want to post this as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. Would be nice if someone could investigate the reason.

Comment: Agreed, though I'm less interested in using knowing it's somehow altering the angular injector/internals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have ng-inspector.org extension installed in chrome, it might be a reason. Just switch off ng-inspector browser extension.

I don't know exact reasons why it's not working with ng-inspector at the moment. If someone have time to look into this, it would be nice to submit bug to project involved (I suspect it's ng-inspector itself).

Comment: This is indeed an issue with version v0.5.9 of ng-inspector. Updating to v0.5.10 (should happen automatically when Chrome is restarted, or you can trigger the update manually by accessing chrome://extensions/ and clicking "Update extensions now"). I'm terribly sorry for everyone that was affected by this issue.

Comment: I've noticed a similar issue with Batarang (0.10.7) enabled. $injector is undefined. Disabling the extension fixes it. ng-inspector: An error occurred attempting to invoke directive: myDirective TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an issue that surfaced with version 0.5.9 of ng-inspector (I'm its maintainer) which was released yesterday. I'm already working on a solution for this, and will release it shortly.

I'm terribly sorry for the inconvenience =(

**Edit:** Just published v0.5.10, should fix this issue. If you encounter further difficulties, feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/rev087/ng-inspector/

Comment: Thanks for confirming the fix! I feel terrible for all the people that must have lost hours trying to debug an issue that wasn't their fault to begin with =(

Answer (score 0):

It should work, without defining the square brackets. The only reason of the square brackets is for js minification.

[AngularJs Directives Link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive,)

Comment: I know. But using the brackets solves this issue. It's only an issue in the latest Chrome. Firefox/Safari don't seem to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I reported yesterday the same issue at the ng-inspector github repo and there is already an attempt to fix it (still don't checked if it's working or not)
https://github.com/rev087/ng-inspector/issues/95#issuecomment-93423284